# How to query data with same join model by difference custom foreign key twice through Sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

## Goal

I have a chat bot project which based on discord and telegram. I stored discord and telegram user data and message they send in database.
Now, I want to search user and count how many users through messages they send, ex: a discord user A send a message "hello world", and a telegram user B also send a message "hello world", I search "hello", then I could get A and B user data, and count 2.

## Tool

- nodes.js: 16.14.2
- sequelize.js: 5.22.4
- postgresql: 14.5

## Database tables

- Users

```
const Users = sequelize.define("Users", {
  name: DataTypes.TEXT,
  userId: DataTypes.TEXT
})
Users.hasMany(models.Messages, {
  as: 'discordMessages',
  sourceKey: 'userId',
  foreignKey: 'discordUserId'
})
Users.hasMany(models.Messages, {
  as: 'telegramMessages',
  sourceKey: 'userId',
  foreignKey: 'telegramUserId'
})
```

I discriminate user from which platform by `userId`.
The data like:

```
name | userId
-------------
A    | 123abc
-------------
B    | 456def
-------------
C    | 789ghi
```

A is a discord user, B is a telegram user

- Messages

```
const Messages = sequelize.define("Messages", {
  message: DataTypes.TEXT,
  discordUserId: DataTypes.TEXT,
  telegramUserId: DataTypes.TEXT
})
Messages.belongsTo(models.Users, {
  as: 'discordMessages',
  targetKey: 'userId',
  foreignKey: 'discordUserId'
})
Messages.belongsTo(models.Users, {
  as: 'telegramMessages',
  targetKey: 'userId',
  foreignKey: 'telegramUserId'
})
```

The relationship between Users and Messages: a user has many messages, a message only belongs to one user.
The data like:

```
message        | discordUserId | telegramUserId
------------------------------------------------
hello world    | 123abc        |
------------------------------------------------
hello world    |               | 456def
------------------------------------------------
sorry.         | 123abc        |
------------------------------------------------
thank you.     |               | 456def
------------------------------------------------
I'm happy      |               | 789ghi
```

## What I've tried

```
const { count, rows } = await Users.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        { '$discordMessages.message$': { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` } },
        { '$telegramMessages.message$': { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` } }
      ]
    },
    include: [
      { model: Messages, as: 'discordMessages' },
      { model: Messages, as: 'telegramMessages' }
    ],
    subQuery: false,
    distinct: true
})
```

This version's code is the closest to what I want, but it's still something wrong. I can't get the right users or counts. I want to get user A and user B, then count 2, but it only return user A. 
The code above return:

```
count: 2
rows: [
    Users: {
      name: 'A',
      userId: '123abc'
    }
]
```

These are some version I also tried:

```
const { count, rows } = await Users.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        { '$discordMessages.message$': { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` } },
        { '$telegramMessages.message$': { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` } }
      ]
    },
    include: [
      { model: Messages, as: 'discordMessages' },
      { model: Messages, as: 'telegramMessages' }
    ],
    subQuery: false,
    distinct: true,
    required: true,
    distinct: true
})
```

```
const { count, rows } = await Users.findAndCountAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Messages,
        as: 'discordMessages',
        where: {
          message: { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` }
        },
        separate: true
      },
      {
        model: Messages,
        as: 'telegramMessages',
        where: {
          message: { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` }
        },
        separate: true
      }
    ],
    subQuery: false,
    distinct: true
})
```

## The result I want:

There are all three users. After query, return two users data have message that I search and tell me two user matched I search.

```
count: 2
rows: [
    Users: {
      name: 'A',
      userId: '123abc'
    },
    Users: {
      name: 'B',
      userId: '456def'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the correct counts in the same query because you have 2 JOINs in the query and that means if you have 2 telegram messages and 3 discord messages then you'll end up with 6 records in total for ONE user. You can try to exclude all attributes in both `discordMessages` and `telegramMessages` but still there is no guarantee you'll get the correct number of users.
The most correct way in case you don't need any data from both `discordMessages` and `telegramMessages` is to use a subquery in `where` option for `User`:

```js
const { count, rows } = await Users.findAndCountAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) from "Messages" where ("Messages"."discordUserId"="User"."userId" OR "Messages"."telegramUserId"="User"."userId") AND ("Messages"."message" ILIKE $search))'), '>', '0'),
   bind: {
     search: `%${search}%`
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I didn't notice I would get the wrong count. Not only wrong count, I also get wrong users. Is any suggestion to get the right users?

Comment: What extra users do you get ? Do they all have no messagea t all or just don't have records with indicated text in the message content?

Comment: It's like I edit. I have three users, and there are two users have message content I want. My code can't give two users data, it only return one user data.

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL and all three records content?